# javacc Expansion within "(...)+" can be matched by empty string error

Tags: java, error-handling, javacc

I'm working on a parser and require custom errors to be thrown for every keyword. My code is the following.

```
SKIP:  { " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }
TOKEN: { "DEF" | "MAIN" | <NAME: (["A"-"Z"])+> | <PARAM: (["a"-"z"])+> | <NUM: (["0"-"9"])+> }

void Start(): {} {(Def() Func())+ <EOF>}

void Def(): {} {"DEF" | { throw new ParseException("expected keyword DEF"); }}

void Func(): {} {"MAIN" | Name() Param() | { throw new ParseException("Expected MAIN or NAME PARAM"); }}

void Name(): {} {<NAME> | { throw new ParseException("invalid function name"); }}

void Param(): {} { <PARAM> | { throw new ParseException("invalid PARAM"); }}
```

The `Start()` function is giving me an error and tells me that `Expansion within "(...)+" can be matched by empty string error`. I think the problem is in the `Name() Param()` part of `Func()` but I do not know how to change this while still throwing custom error messages. Can anyone provide some pointers?

Comment: Don't do this. It will never work. Just accept the syntax errors you get from the generated parser.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the comment from user207421, you could maybe do the following

```
void oneOrMoreThings() : {} {
    (Thing() | (throw new ParseException( ... ) ; }
    ( Thing() )*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make DEF optional and then check it has been found and if not raise the exception.

```java
Start(): {Token tk=null;} {tk="DEF"? {if (tk==null) throw ...} "MAIN" etc
```

Comment: Please use code formatting to improve your answer. thank you